# Replace string of text and capture what is in the middle

Tags: sed

I'm editing a LaTeX  document, and I need to change all instances of `\parallel something \parallel` to `\norm{something}`. Sometimes, there's no space between the "\parallel"'s and "something". I'm trying to use

```
$ sed -i 's/\\parallel[.*]\\parallel/\\norm\{\1\}/g' a.txt  $
```

but it returns an error of "Invalid reference". What is the correct `sed` code?

Answer (score 4):

When you do this:

```
$ sed -i 's/\\parallel[.*]\\parallel/\\norm\{\1\}/g' a.txt
```

, you are not using capture groups.

In `[]` you specify the character class. Character class is couple of symbols that can be replaced with one of them. Thus, RE like `[.*]` matches exactly one of `.` or `*`, not «any sequence of characters».

Capture groups are denoted by `\(RE\)`. Thus, you should replace `[]` with `\(\)`, like this:

```
$ sed -i 's/\\parallel\(.*\)\\parallel/\\norm{\1}/g' a.txt
```

, and you will be able to access it with `\1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i -e 's/\\parallel\s\+\(.*\S\)\s*\\parallel/\\norm {\1}/g' a.txt
```

`\1` in the replace string refers to the first `\(`...`\)` in the search pattern.

If you prefere the "extended" regular expression syntax, then

```
sed -i -r -e 's/\\parallel\s+(.*\S)\s*\\parallel/\\norm \{\1\}/g' a.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

**replace:**

```
$ sed -i 's/\\parallel[.*]\\parallel/\\norm\{\1\}/g' a.txt $
```

**with this:**

```
$ sed -i 's/\\parallel\(.*\)\\parallel/\\norm\{\1\}/g' a.txt
```

That should work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about something so i used [:alnum:]

```
sed -r 's#\\parallel[ ]*([[:alnum:]]+)[ ]*\\parallel#\\norm{\1}#g'
```